# How to combine 2 different filters

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, filter

I created this simple filter for date interval, and different levels (0,1,2). I have this code so far:

```
if(isset($_POST['filtersubmit'])){
    $datex = str_replace('/', '-', $_POST['firstdate']);
    $date1 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($datex));
    $datey = str_replace('/', '-', $_POST['lastdate']);
    $date2 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($datey));
    $projects = $_POST['projekt'];



    if(isset($date1) && isset($date2)){
        $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM zapasy WHERE datum BETWEEN 
        '$date1' AND '$date2' ORDER BY id DESC");
    }  


    if($projects == 0){
        $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM zapasy WHERE projekt = '0' ORDER BY id DESC") or die(mysqli_errno($conn). '-'. mysqli_error($conn));
    } elseif($projects == 1){
        $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM zapasy WHERE projekt = '1' ORDER BY id DESC") or die(mysqli_errno($conn). '-'. mysqli_error($conn));
    } elseif($projects == 2){
        $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM zapasy WHERE projekt = '2' ORDER BY id DESC") or die(mysqli_errno($conn). '-'. mysqli_error($conn));
    } 
}
```

Now if I select just one of these filters, it works good, but if I want both interval and level filters, it doesn't work. I am not really sure how to do it. I am really grateful for any help.

Comment: Why are you using php if-else when you have `WHERE` condition in sql query? You can pass php variable in query too

Comment: @ZainFarooq  Do you mean  $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM zapasy WHERE projekt1 = '$projects' ORDER BY id DESC");   ??

Comment: Yes.. but for preventing sql injections you should use pdo or prepared statements

Comment: @ZainFarooq MySQLi can use prepared statements just fine. PDO doesn't automatically prevent SQL injection, you need to bind the values - as you need in MySQLi.

Comment: @Qirel Yes. pdo with bind values

Comment: @ZainFarooq Or `mysqli_` with `bind_param()`.

Comment: What format are your input dates? Y/m/d or d/m/Y?

Comment: Try this `SELECT * FROM zapasy WHERE projekt = '$project' AND datum BETWEEN 
   '$date1' AND '$date2' ORDER BY id DESC`

Comment: @ZainFarooq It just selects all with $project

Comment: @Nick  MM/DD/YYY that is why I change it before I use it to Y-m-d  (that is how 
 I saved dates in db

Comment: Hmm Add `OR` in place of `AND`

Comment: `SELECT * FROM zapasy WHERE projekt = '$project' OR (datum BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2') ORDER BY id DESC`

Comment: I wonder how your interval filter works alone

Comment: @ZainFarooq it works, it selects these dates well, the problem is to combine them, I tried this for so long. But I didn't succeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use something along these lines, using a prepared statement to protect you from SQL injection. Basically we form arrays of `WHERE` clauses, parameters and parameter types from each filter if it is present in the `$_POST` array. These are then imploded into the query, parameters are bound and the query executed.

```
if (isset($_POST['filtersubmit'])) {
    $params = array();
    $paramtypes = array();
    $wheres = array();
    if (isset($_POST['firstdate'], $_POST['lastdate'])) {
        $date1 = date_create_from_format('m/d/Y', $_POST['firstdate']);
        $date2 = date_create_from_format('m/d/Y', $_POST['lastdate']);
        if (!empty($date1) && !empty($date2)) {
            array_push($params, $date1->format('Y-m-d'), $date2->format('Y-m-d'));
            array_push($paramtypes, 's', 's');
            array_push($wheres, 'datum BETWEEN ? AND ?');
        }
    }
    if (isset($_POST['projekt'])) {
        $project = $_POST['projekt'];
        if (is_numeric($project) && $project >= 0 && $project <= 2) {
            array_push($params, $project);
            array_push($paramtypes, 'i');
            array_push($wheres, 'projekt = ?');
        }
    }
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM zapasy';
    if (count($wheres)) {
        $sql .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $wheres);
    }
    $sql .= ' ORDER BY id DESC';
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql) or die($conn->error);
    if (count($wheres)) {
        $stmt->bind_param(implode('', $paramtypes), ...$params);
    }
    $stmt->execute() or die($stmt->error);
    // bind results
    $stmt->bind_result(/* variables corresponding to each field in SELECT */);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        // do something with the data
    }
}
```

Comment: What variable is the finale query?

Comment: The final query is in `$sql`

Comment: In what way isn't it working? Are you getting any error messages? Is it selecting the wrong data? Or ???

Comment: i am not getting any data

Comment: Note that with prepared statements you need to bind the result values as well. Are you doing that? See my edit and also the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php)